# How is the healing stat calculated in Diablo 3?

Tags: diablo-iii

Can someone explain how come this gray item *without any healing stats* heals 12% better than a legendary?

[Click for bigger picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGRvm.jpg)

[image: Screenshot showing comparison between two weapons]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Flail has a much faster attack speed so you benefit more from Life on Hit if you have any on your gear. Thus getting 12.5% bonus healing.

To further extend my answer, healing affixes are :

- Life on Hit
- Life after kill
- Life per second
- Life per resource spent (only for melee classes)

The healing stat is the game's estimation of how much life you can regenerate over a period of 1 second depending on what healing affixes you are using on your gear. The exact calculation is unknown but it's safe to assume that Life on Hit is more efficient with a high attack rate.

It's important to note aswell, since patch [patch 2.1.2](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/17561388/patch-212-now-live-1-13-2015#general) :

> The "Healing" stat on the character sheet has been replaced with
> "Recovery". Recovery is an estimate of how much Toughness you are
> expected to be able to recover in combat and is calculated using a
> combination of your Healing, Life, and Toughness.The Healing number
> will still be viewable in the character sheet if you mouse over the
> Recovery stat

which is in my opinion more accurate.